# What regulations, agreements, or other forces can help mitigate "PrankSats"?

Tags: launch, cubesat, regulatory

**comment:** I've used a somewhat innocuous abstraction of 'pranks in space' below, but there's no end to the trouble that could be caused and the increasing ease with which a state (nation or otherwise) could cause it. The scope of [Article IX of The Outer Space Treaty **of 1967**](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Outer_Space_Treaty_of_1967#Article_IX) is pretty narrow - what exactly happens if party A says that party B may be in violation of article IX? Is there a board of arbitration? Are there any mechanisms of 'punishment' established? What about a non-signatory state? Misdeeds on earth are getting easier to detect and report by independent news media, but how many news orgs have NORAD's capability?

The discussion in the recent article in The Conversation: [SpaceX explosion shows why we must slow down private space exploration until we rewrite law](https://theconversation.com/spacex-explosion-shows-why-we-must-slow-down-private-space-exploration-until-we-rewrite-law-65019) focuses mostly on accident and liability issues, and points out that the 50 year old [Outer Space Treaty](http://www.unoosa.org/oosa/en/ourwork/spacelaw/treaties/introouterspacetreaty.html) ratified [in 1967](http://www.state.gov/t/isn/5181.htm) may need to be dusted off and looked at more closely. I'd recommend reading the full article - here is a paragraph near the end:

> With the increase in private participation in space experimentation and perhaps even mineral mining, the provisions governing civil liability over mishaps arising from the operations of a space station are likely to become one of the most contested areas of space law. What if a module or component part fails to function on a space station? In the absence of multilateral rules on this point, a patchwork of legal rules is gradually maintained through MOUs (Memorandum of Understanding) and other national laws such as the US Commercial Space Launchings Act (CSLA) of 1978. How will private companies fit into these as they possibly become partners?

Further, the "PrankSat" situations may multiply when it becomes more and more common to add significant propulsion capability to cubesats, and control may not be under the same number of levels of security that is currently used for "serious" satellites.

Other terms that may apply in some cases include "tit for tat-sat" and "a proportional response-sat."

[image]

**above:** Outer Space Treaty parties, signatories, and non-signatories as of March 2015 from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Outer_Space_Treaty_parties.svg), modified by pasting legend (sorry Antarctica).

---

If a hypothetical President Wisenheimer felt secure that his/her country's large supply of neodymium, palladium and [unobtainium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtainium) gives them some economic protection, what international regulations, agreements, or other forces could help the rest of the world stop, or at least discourage the president from allowing his/her brother in law's aerospace company *OrbitalPranksters* from launching PrankSat and putting it in orbit in front of the [Hubble Space Telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble_Space_Telescope)?

[image]

[image]

The pranksters know what a collimator is, and understand that the basic point-to-parallel-to-point method will add to the image on the CCD even if it significantly under-fills the telescope's aperture. It will be in focus at all distances since both have infinity conjugate focci. (image [from a randomly chosen internet optics catalog](http://www.trioptics.com/downloads/)), and here are some [other collimators](http://www.pyser-sgi.com/images/added/pdf/SAC.pdf) that project images into telescopes.

[image]

PrankSat could navigate near the HST, or - since the divergence of the FOV is small - intercept the scheduled HST view from kilometers away and "Flash". It could also attach itself to the HST in some way, occasionally move into view, and really become a pest.

[image]

**above:** I found this on the internet. Used with warm regards to [Dr. Tyson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_deGrasse_Tyson) and all he does to further the public's understanding of science.

Comment: Look at the [outer space treaty](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Outer_Space_Treaty_of_1967#Article_IX), article 9, for example.

Comment: @2012rcampion I've used a somewhat innocuous abstraction of 'pranks in space' but there's no end to the trouble that could be caused and the increasing ease with which a state (nation or otherwise) could cause it. The scope of that paragraph is pretty narrow - what exactly happens if party A says that party B may be in violation of article IX? Is there a board of arbitration? Are there any mechanisms of 'punishment' established? What about a non-signatory state? Misdeeds on earth are getting easier to detect and report by independent news media, but how many news orgs have NORAD's capability?

Comment: @uhoh I'm afraid I have to agree with what the others are saying. There's no tangible regulation on the situation you're aiming for because it can't happen yet. When it becomes more feasible, then you *will* see action. Until then, the answer to what you seem to be aiming for is speculation.

Comment: Orbital mechanics (no stable orbit that stays in the field of view) and optics (anything within a few km will be so out of focus as to be invisible) are other reasons to make this stupid idea impossible...

Comment: @called2voyage Ill-willed and malicious satellite behavior is not only possible but has already happened at least a few times. I wanted to keep the example scenario a bit oblique - I'm not going to outline a really bad scenario here in SX SE and I'm not going to respond to requests here to provide it. But for another hypothetical example: as cubesats get Iodine or H2O based propulsion would they be automatically blocked from gentle deployment from the ISS? A sat with propulsion can in fact return and cause trouble in that case.  Are amateur cubesats' command and control absolutely unhackable?

Comment: @pericynthion look at the optics again - it is correctly configured. The photo is at the focal point of the mirror, the conjugate focus is at infinity, as is the telescope's. point-to-parallel, then parallel to point. The satellite has thrust and plenty of light, so it can maneuver into position, flash during a long exposure, and then move out. A prank - thus the name chosen. The physics is correct here. I've added the drawing of a collimator for clarification.

Comment: If nobody posts a high-quality answer in another day or so, I'll probably try to delete this question as it seems to be attracting some flippancy and condescendence but little serious thought.

Comment: @uhoh I'm not being dismissive. I took quite some time to consider your question. I understand what you're getting at, but I'm afraid trying to approach it in such a generalized manner will make it unanswerable--at least in the sense that you won't be able to get the answer you're looking for. I understand you wanting to avoid specific scenarios, but I think that's really the only way to go here.

Comment: @called2voyage No you're not at all! I see what you mean. I'm still trying to get my "sea legs" here in SE. OK lemme think about the best way to proceed with this question. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/1730/) Won!

Comment: @JanDoggen [twice now](https://xkcd.com/1992/)! I've voted to temporarily re-open to allow for 1992 to be an answer. Otherwise I could add it to the question, but I prefer to let XKCD have the final word. Prefer someone besides me to post that answer if you or someone is up to it, re-closing afterword would be fine.

Answer (score 9):

For your specific example, the answer is **cost**.  Nobody is going to spend hundreds of millions (or even just 1% of that) just to prank a community of astronomers.

For other examples?  What stops China or Russia from launching a set of rockets to destroy GPS satellites, or military communication satellites?  Neither country wants to initiate World War III.  What stops a private company from doing the same?  Cost, technological capability, laws, negative consequences, lack of positive consequences, etc.  Even though private space industry is coming up, it's still heavily government regulated.  If a private company in Russia were to launch a set of rockets from Russia that just happen to destroy the GPS constellation (why the heck would they do that?), the Kremlin probably should expect a phone call from the White House, and quite likely somewhat more than that.  If Inmarsat were to launch a set of rockets destroying the Iridium constellation, they won't stay in business terribly long.

Comment: Thanks! There are states and nations who are not currently taking any calls from the White House. I understand the idea that - I'll try to paraphrase - nobody would do anything bad in space because it wouldn't make sense, but like developing a nuclear warhead in the late 20th and early 21st century, stuff happens.

Comment: @uhoh "There are states and nations who are not currently taking any calls from the White House" -- North Korea is the only one I can think of, actually, given that an attack on GPS is an attack on a US military asset and the US might decide to communicate via cruise missile. And North Korea takes China's calls, and China takes the US's calls.

Comment: North Korea is also quite far from being able to physically attack GPS or other (US military) satellites.  Hitting a satellite is not easy, those things are *fast*.

Comment: @cpast This question is about *regulations, agreements, or other forces can help mitigate* behavior of a satellite in space that causes trouble to another satellite. It is not "please name one specific example of bad behavior in space and explain why that one example won't happen" or "why wouldn't someone harm the US-operated GPS satellite constellation?" My comment about nukes "in the late 20th and early 21st century" is an *example* of behavior (by multiple countries, not just one) that is costly but doesn't necessarily make sense to address the idea that *cost alone* would be sufficient.

Comment: The cost of the proposed 3U cubesat with COTS ADCS, solar panels, a mirror, LED, and a picture of Dr. Tyson is probably of order *one million* dollars, not "hundreds of millions" as stated in your answer, unless of course he sues for defamation! ;-)

Comment: @uhoh Without orbit control, you wouldn't be able to navigate it in front of the hubble.

Comment: @gerrit the nice things about attitude thrusters is that they can be used in different combinations; some pairs produce torque-only, other pairs produce thrust-only, with no torque.

Answer (score -2):

The answer, as gerrit has eluded to, is that going to space is **hard** and **expensive,** which places it outside the realm of even the most dedicated pranksters.

For example, assuming you can get your pranksat a launch, there is a bevy of launch-vehicle levied requirements on how your pranksat must be designed. Each of those needs to be validated through (most likely) testing, to ensure that your payload will not harm the launch vehicle (for example, by shaking apart in its container.) The facilities and knowledge to execute such testing and design is expensive.

There's also a ton of national and international bureaucracy involved in going to space. How would you talk to your prospective pranksat? You'd likely use radio, which in the United States places you under the thumb of the FCC. It would be difficult to convince the safety-oriented bureaucrats at the FCC that a pranksat is worth allocating the radio bandwidth.

Finally, the act of conducting rendezvous is non-trivial; determining a spacecraft's orientation and position requires  specialized hardware and software that requires considerable expertise to construct. Additionally, flying around near other spacecraft is a great way to collide with them, causing at the very least an international incident and at the worst a major debris-causing incident.

While cubesats are becoming more common, the factors outlined above place hard constraints on the cost and inherent risk of building the type of pranksat you outline.

Comment: [41332 and 41333](http://edition.cnn.com/2016/02/06/asia/north-korea-rocket-launch-window/)

Comment: 747's cost a few hundred million dollars a piece - and yet cost didn't stop them from being used 'irrationally' in quite a heinous but effective manner, bureaucracy or federal laws didn't stop it either. There are too many states, nations, and groups who wouldn't mind at all if they caused an international incident. Consider that [Piracy at sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piracy_off_the_coast_of_Somalia) has been costing US$ 6 billion per year in trade even though "it's against the rules and international agreements." See [also](http://oceansbeyondpiracy.org/reports/sop2015/west-africa).

Comment: I was responding to your question - "what international regulations, agreements, or other forces could help the rest of the world stop [such a thing]?" If you're going to ignore how hard it would be to launch and the international relations issues involved, the question boils down to "what would stop someone dedicated to causing problems from doing so," which is only tangentially related to space in this case.

As with piracy, the better question is - what would motivate them to do so, given the large incentives not to?

Comment: There isn't an international space force dedicated to policing orbit, if that's what you're getting at. The inherent technical difficulties and international risks are the bar, but if you're willing to overcome those, you can go ruin whoever's mission you wanted in orbit.

Comment: @AndrewH. For better or worse... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Space_Force