# ISS - Tiangong 2 minimum safe distance

Tags: iss, safety, collision-avoidance, tiangong-2

Using the SGP4 propagator, I calculated the minimum distance between ISS and Tiangong-2 for this year.

I obtained 12.32 km for `2017-09-27 17:29:36.376 UTC` (which is the day `270.7289`). I used the TLE `17270.72310185` for the ISS and the TLE `17270.58030751` for the Tiangong-2.

That distance seems very small. Is there any minimum safe distance to keep?

EDIT: I uploaded the graphs that I use to analyze the close encounter geometry: http://cristianopi.altervista.org/_Incontri.html (Sat1 = ISS, Sat2 = TG2).

Comment: Slightly related; [Is 45 km unusually close to pass the ISS and deploy a microsatellite without warning?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18991/12102) and also [Is 75 meters an exceptionally close distance for two satellites to pass at >6,000 m/s?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19405/12102).

Comment: Also, see answer to [What is the “ISS's Keep Out Sphere” and what is its radius?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20814/12102)

Comment: Believe it or not, a distance of 12 km for the two stations is probably safer then 12 km for two random pieces of debris. The space stations are known to a very high precision, and thus that far of distance is pretty much guaranteed to be real.

Comment: Wow, from this distance they could even see eachother! (If it happens on the sunny side)

Comment: I've edited to bump to the active queue. Do you remember the relative orientation? Did one pass mostly above the other, were they moving nearly parallel, or was there a substantial angle between the two meaning that the relative velocity would have been of the order of a kilometer/sec and therefore almost too fast to see (if one were looking at the other)? fyi I've just asked [Has an astronaut ever seen another object in LEO pass by that wasn't mission-related in any way?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38958/12102)

Comment: @uhoh please, see the EDIT.

Comment: okay I'll have a look, thanks!