# Why Celestrak has Archived TLEs for most space stations from Russia and the US, but not Tiangong-1, Tiangong-2 or Skylab?

Tags: two-line-elements, tiangong-1, skylab, tiangong-2, celestrak

Thinking about [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30185/12102), I wanted to look at historical data. Then I noticed that while Celestrak does provide [Archived TLE data](https://celestrak.org/NORAD/archives/) for Salyut 7, Mir, Kvant-1, Kvant-2, Kristallm, Spektr, Priroda, and ISS (Zarya), it does not provide data for the recent [Tiangong-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiangong-1) and [Tiangong-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiangong-2) stations, nor for [Skylab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylab) which was in orbit from 1973 to 1979.

*Why not?*

I'm wondering if there are any governing international agreements, policies, courtesies or considerations involved, or if this is just random happenstance.

**edit:** For this particular question which has remained unanswered for a month, I'll be interested in thoughtful speculation, if that's what it takes to address this.

[image: Celestrak Archived TLEs]

Comment: No idea about the Tiangongs, but I note that Celestrak was established in 1985, at which point Salyut 7 was up, but Skylab was not. The Archived TLE data page says 1980-2004, but there's a link to request earlier data.

Comment: Also, took the liberty of correcting your Skylab date.

Comment: @RussellBorogove Yikes, thank you! Yes, it was 1979 when I was wearing my "Skylab is Falling" tee shirt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@RussellBorogove's [comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/30220/why-celestrak-has-archived-tles-for-most-space-stations-from-russia-and-the-us#comment89837_30220) is fairly conclusive.

> ...I note that Celestrak was established in 1985, at which point Salyut 7 was up, but Skylab was not. The Archived TLE data page says 1980-2004, but there's a link to request earlier data.

Skylab reentered the atmosphere *before 1980* and Tiangong-1 and Tiangong-2 were both launched *after 2004*.

And, as also pointed out there; data for them can be obtained by Celestrak's special request feature.

Comment: first sentence [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/17308/12102) ;-)